# Is there a way to convert a dataframe to geojson file to import it in the QGIS vector layer?

Tags: python, pandas, geojson, qgis, multipolygons

How to write dataframe contains list of multipolygon data to geojson file in order to import in QGIS?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kmo0.png)

I'm trying to convert this pandas dataframe to a geojson file (to import into QGIS to see the polygons there). But I don't know how to convert a df that contains list of multipolygon data for each gid.
How could I do this?

Comment: Please provide the output of `df.head(5).to_dict()` please?

Comment: Provide example data not snap shots of picture, if you ask for help, please.

Comment: @Corralien I just added the output of the first 2 data in my df

Comment: [Don't use image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is the format of your input file, it looks like a geojson file?

Comment: @Corralien sorry, my very first time upload a post
Here is an example of the output for a gid: 
https://mangomap.com/maps/57773854-364e-11e7-8d85-06c182e4d011/get_feature_geo_json?shape_table_name=shp_0e1f6bb6_6cd2_11ed_b0e8_027d7e0bb32b&gid=46&zoom_level=22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way is to use [`geopandas`](https://geopandas.org) and [`gdf.to_file()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_file.html)

```
import geopandas as gpd

# Convert DataFrame to GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='my_geo_column')

# Export data to GeoJSON
gdf.to_file('output.geojson')
```

Comment: the my_geo_column is just the column 'content', isn't it?

Comment: oh i got it, transformed the coordinates to Multipolygon type and it worked, then I'll try to import it in QGIS

Comment: Yes it should be.

Comment: I successfully imported the geojson file into Vector Layer in QGIS, you save me.